# Highchart grouped_categories plugin add scrollbar feature to the chart

Tags: highcharts

Got any ideas to add scrollbar on grouped_categories chart

Grouped_categories refer: [http://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories/](http://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories)

I have try to use the

```
scrollbar: {
  enabled: true
},
```

Scrollbar feature refer: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/scrollbar

however it can't work [codepen](https://codepen.io/Ho-Chun-Ang/pen/gOZXERO)

Scrollbar on grouped_categories chart

Answer (score 1):

The link you sent to the documentation refers to `chart.scrollablePlotArea` which allows you to set a scrollbar for regular charts. The `axis.scrollbar` functionality you are trying to use is in the Highstock library so you would need to import it for it to work. But it also involves the required license for this product.

```js
chart: {
  scrollablePlotArea: {
    minWidth: 700,
    scrollPositionX: 1
  }
}
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yqn890oh/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.scrollablePlotArea